# Why Xcode doesn't show me deprecated methods?

Tags: xcode

I have an issue with Xcode. While I was working with Android Studio, it showed me deprecated methods once I used them. However, when it comes to Xcode, it doesn't show me deprecated methods. Look at the image below:
[image: Xcode 1]

[image: Xcode 2]

According to Apple's docs, the ".navigationBarTitle" is deprecated, however Xcode doesn't light it up.

### Code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                Spacer()
                    .navigationBarTitle("title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: So your question is why Xcode is not behaving like some other IDE you have used?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

If look at code where ".navigationBarTitle" is declared I see this code:

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use navigationTitle(_:) with navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(_:)")
@available(macOS, unavailable)
@available(tvOS, unavailable)
@available(watchOS, unavailable)
public func navigationBarTitle(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, displayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode) -> some View
```

It has different redeclarations, but here no any words about ".navigationBarTitle" is deprecated. It's presented in ios13, will be deprecated in ios100000 :).

XCode shows deprecated methods for sure, but it also depends of used minimaldeveloper ios version you use - if you use some old ios versions - you can not see messages, because of code is "not yet" deprecated for used minimal version.

Update:
here I attach the image showing XCode deprecation message.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, strange. On the Apple docs site, it shows that it is deprecated. Look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitle(_:)-6p1k7

Comment: Yes, it's marked as Deprecated, but only from iOS100000.0 . For all currently available iOS versions since 13.0 it will work like a charm.